# text area in form - cursor won't start at the top

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm working on a contact form and have two queries:

1. the text area displays correctly, but when the user starts typing in it, the cursor begins 2 lines down (and also the text runs over one line (i.e. keeps going in one long straight line) rather than staying within the box borders
2. I'd like to add inline styling for the label but I can't seem to get the styling code in the right place.

View code:

```
  = simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
    .field
      = f.input :name, input_html: { class: 'gtb_text_field' }
    .field
      = f.input :email, input_html: { class: 'gtb_text_field' }
    -#.field
      -#= f.input :type, as: :select, collection: WHY_CONTACT, label: 'Type of enquiry', allow_blank: false
    .form_field_wrapper
      = f.input :message, label: 'My message' , input_html: {class: 'gtb_text_area', style: 'margin-left: 50px; width: 310px;'}
    .actions
      = f.submit  'Send message', class: 'signup_button'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What kind of javascript libs/do you have on this page? Do you use any CSS framework (Bootstrap, Zurb)? And most importantly, you'd need to paste the HTML source of that view.

Comment: Ah, ok, that helped point me in the right direction and I have actually solved the problem. Thanks